# Java serialized class has values that reset to null outside of method that fills them

Tags: java, class

So here is the issue. I have defined two serialized classes in a jar library similar to what is shown below.

```
public class CfgEntry implements Serializable {
    // Array of towers 
    public ArrayList<TwrData> twrArrayList = new ArrayList<TwrData>();

FillTowerArray();
PrintFields(twrArrayList.get(twrArrayList.size()-1)) // Print the last entry

private void FillTowerArray(){
        // Only placing one entry in the arraylist
        newTwr = new TwrData();
        newTwr.twrName = "twr1";
        newTwr.twrType = "r";
        newTwr.rtName "rt1";

        twrArrayList.add(newTwr);
  
        PrintFields(twrArrayList.get(twrArrayList.size()-1)) // Print instance just added
    }         
}

public class TwrData implements Serializable {
    // Serialized declaration to get rid of warning
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String twrName;
    public String twrType;
    public String rtName;

    public TwrData() {
        // Set default values
        twrName = "";
        twrType = "";
        rtName = "";
    }
}
```

They are packaged together and exported to a jar file that I reference in my main GUI program. Everything worked as designed until recently when I added the field "rtName" to the TwrData class. I added code to print out the values of the fields for testing. When they print from inside the FillTwrArray method all the fields are populated, however, when they print again after the method exits only the old fields are populated and the new field that I added is null. I've cleaned and rebuilt the jar library and the main GUI, removed all files and stated again and the result is the same. Any idea what could cause this

I would expect that any new fields I add to my class would be accessible once I rebuilt everything. They are accessible but do not stay assigned. It seems like a scope issue but all the old values stick.

Comment: Did you change the value of `TwrData.serialVersionUID` when you added a new persistent field to that class?  What you describe is *precisely* the scenario where that is needful.

Comment: And if that elicits different behavior, then that's probably because your application is trying to read serialized instances of the old version of the class according to the new version of the class.  The easiest solution to such a problem is simply to clean all those old serialized objects out of the system.  It gets a lot more complicated if you need somehow to preserve those data.

Comment: Also, are you sure that all components of the system are using the same version of the `TwrData` class?

Comment: @JohnBollinger No it isn’t. Adding a field is serialization-compatible, and no reason to change the serialVersionUID. See the Java Object Serialization Specification, *Object Versioning* chapter. Whatever the issue is here, it has nothing to do with serialVersionUID. Changing that would only cause another problem.